# best way to check for new xml files in java

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, file, jdbc

i am writing a program that parses xml files that hold tourist attractions for cities.  each city has it's own xml and the nodes have info like cost, address etc...  i want to have a thread on a timer to check for new xml files or more recent versions of existing ones in a specific directory.  creating the thread is not the problem.  i just have no idea what the best way to check for these new files or changed files is.  does anyone have any suggestions as to an easy way to make do that. i was thinking of crating a csv file with names and date altered info for each file processed and then checking against this csv file when i go to check for new or altered xml, but that seems overly complicated and i would like a better solution.  i have no code to offer at this point for this mechanism i am just looking for a direction to go in.
the idea is as i get xml's for different cities fitting the schema that it will update my db automatically next time the program runs or periodically if already running.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid polling you should watch the directory containing the xml file. Oracle has an extensive documentation about the topic at [Watching a Directory for Changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing looks like asynchronous feeding of new info. One common pitfall on such problem is race condition : what happens if you are trying to read a file while it's being modified or if something else tries to write a file while you are reading it ? What happens if your app (or the app that edit your xml files) breaks in the middle of processing ? To avoid such problems you should move files (change name or directory) to follow their status because moves are atomical operation on normal file systems. If you want a bullet proof solution, you should have :

- files being edited or transfered by an external part
- files being fully edited or transfered and ready to be read by you app
- files being processed
- files completely processed
- files containing errors (tried to process them but could not complete processing)

The 2 first are under external responsability (you just define an interface contract), the 2 latter are under yours. The cost if 4 or 5 directories (if you choose that solution), the gains are :

- if there is any problem while editing-tranfering a xml file, the external app just have to restart its operation
- if a file can't be processed (syntax error, oversized, ...) it is put apart for further analysis but does not prevent processing of other files
- you only have to watch almost empty directories
- if your app breaks in the middle of processing a file, at next start it can restart its processing.